# LM test interpretation in VAR - a joint hypotheses test? (In EViews)

Tags: autocorrelation, vector-autoregression

This question is about how to interpret LM test in VAR.

For example, under VAR with lag 1, the LM test shows

```
lags----LM-stat----Prob
1-------34.73------0.0043
2-------21.76------0.1508
```

Oh! auto-correlation in lag 1! So, I rerun VAR with 1 more lag. Then the result of LM test under VAR with 2 lags is

```
lags---LM-stat-----Prob 
1------31.37932----0.0120
2------10.62227----0.8322
3------20.56224----0.1960
```

Now my VAR has autocorrelation or not? According to my knowledge (i dont have much technical knowledge), standard LM test is a joint test. But the way EViews manual's description looks like LM test under VAR is not a joint hypotheses test. Which means, in my case, I still suffer auto-correlation at lag 1 under VAR(2), RIGHT?

Say, even I have a VAR(6) system, if the LM test result is:

```
Lags---LM-Stat-----Prob
1------34.43359----0.0047
2------24.91163----0.0714
3------20.13258----0.2143
4------9.748399----0.8794
5------16.69178----0.4058
6------22.46036----0.1289
7------11.65195----0.7676
```

I still suffer autocorrelation at lag 1, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [EViews manual](http://www.eviews.com/help/helpintro.html#page/content/VAR-Views_and_Procs_of_a_VAR.html), *Autocorrelation LM Test [r]eports the multivariate LM test statistics for residual serial correlation up to the specified order*. So it is a joint test just as it should be (because of *up to the specified order* rather than *at some particular order* or the like). Where did you find written otherwise?

> Now my VAR has autocorrelation or not?

At lag 1 there is rather strong evidence against no autocorrelation ($p$-value of 1.2%) but less so when you take the first two or the first three lags jointly ($p$-values of 83.2% and 19.6%, respectively).

> I still suffer auto-correlation at lag 1 under VAR(2), RIGHT?

Yes, you do, as explained above.

> I still suffer autocorrelation at lag 1, right?

Yes, you do, because here the $p$-value is just 0.47%.

Comment: I thank you very very much for your time! Actually, I looked at the same page on EViews  as you did..I think I misunderstood it.... One last question: As you said, my VAR (2) model does not suffer from auto correlation when considering first two and three lags jointly...So, does this mean I can use VAR(2) or VAR(3) model? Or, in other words, can I claim that my VAR(2) model residual is white noise (assume other assumptions not violated)? ...... What makes me confused is that should I always make sure all my lags has no autocorrelation in order to claim my VAR has no autocorrelation problem?

Comment: @YunqingMa, No, you cannot claim the residuals are white noise because there is autocorrelation at lag 1. All lags should be clean (with high $p$-values).